# Inheritance of templates - assignement failed

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I run into a trouble with templates and inheritance. Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TemplateBase {
public: 
    TemplateBase() {}
};


class TemplateA: public TemplateBase {
public:     
    TemplateA():TemplateBase() {}
};

template <class T>
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
};

class Derived: public Base<TemplateA> {
public:
    Derived(): Base() {}
};

int main()
{
    Base<TemplateBase>* a = new Base<TemplateBase>(); // ok
    Base<TemplateA>* b = new Derived(); // ok
    Base<TemplateBase>* c = new Derived(); // error: cannot convert ‘Derived*’ to ‘Base<TemplateBase>*’ in initialization
}
```

The problem is the assignment of pointer `c`, which fails from unknown reason for me. I am trying to assign the `Derived<AnotherDerived>` to `Base<AnotherBase>`, is this possible?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Derived` is a non-template class derived from `Base<TemplateA>`. In the line

```
Base<TemplateBase>* c = new Derived();
```

you are trying to refer to a `Derived` object via a pointer to `Base<TemplateBase>`. For the compiler, there is no relation between `Base<TemplateBase>` and `Derived`, hence it fails. The only possible base to use is `Base<TemplateA>` from which `Derived` is derived.

A possible solution is to templatize the `Derived`, like

```
template<typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T> {
public:
    Derived(): Base<T>() {}
};
```

then use as

```
Base<TemplateBase>* c = new Derived<TemplateBase>;
```

See a [live example here](http://ideone.com/Eie4Fv).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Is it then possible to assign an instance of `Derived` class into a "general, more abstract" variable type? I have several variations of `Derived`, and I would like to create factory class, which would return an instance of some type, but now I don't know, which type I should use... Is this somehow possible?

Comment: @dohnto see the updated edit for a possible solution

Comment: vsoftco, @TartanLlama thank you very much for quick answers,  I see, that my approach is not valid and I have to use a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

vsoftco gives a good outline of why this is invalid. An example of why this is the case in C++ is that although `TemplateBase` and `TemplateA` are related, `Base<TemplateBase>` and `Base<TemplateA>` are completely different. We could even specialize `Base` in a way which makes them have an incompatible interface:

```
template<>
struct Base<TemplateBase>
{
    Base() = delete;
    Base(int i) {}
}
```

Now it's obvious that `Base<TemplateBase>` and `Base<TemplateA>` can't be used in the same way, because one is default-constructable and one isn't. As such, it's impossible to use them polymorphically, because the compiler won't know what code to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism says a base class pointer can point to a derived class object. 
But the same can't happen for templates.

- Since Polymorphism is a dynamic feature and bound at run-time.
- Templates are a static feature and bound at the compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You make a common mistake, you think that relation between classes:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
```

Will propagate this relation to templates:

```
template <class T>
class Tmpl {};


Tmpl<A> a; Tmpl<B> b;
a = b; // fails!
```

So you expected that `Tmpl<A>` would be a parent to `Tmpl<B>` but that is not the case. To simulate that you would need to make a constructor, that allows such conversion:

```
template <class T>
class Tmpl {
   T data;
public:
   Tmpl() : data() {}
   template<class Parent>
   Tmpl( const Tmpl<Parent> &t ) : data( t.data ) {}
};

Tmpl<A> a; Tmpl<B> b;
a = b; // works!
```

For details you should look into smart pointer implementation, there is similar problem there - assignment from pointer to child from base needs to work.

Answer (score -1):

The `Derived` class is derived from `Base<TemplateA>` so `Base<TemplateBase>* c = new Derived()` is equivalent to saying 
`Base<TemplateBase>* c = new Base<TemplateA>()` which is incorrect because `Base<TemplateA>` is a different class altogether. 
`TemplateBase` is a base class for `TemplateA` but same does not hold true for `Base<TemplateBase>` and `Base<TemplateA>`.